# Random Seed gives different numbers after game shutdown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random-seed

I'm working on a puzzle game like water sort. I'm the only person in this project so I decided to make levels with a random level generator that uses Random seeds. Everything was okay then I realized if is game shutting down random seed values are changing. This change will affect all levels that will be created and make them different. I don't want it. My part of the color-picking code is below. Other things like bottle amount etc. are written same logic.

Edit: I'm generating a level in another thread because of that I can't use classic Random.Range.
Edit2: Generated number is saving a JSON file and getting in `Awake` method.

```cs
public class LevelColorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int GetRandomColorIndex(Data data)
    {
        var hashString = "GetRandomColor " + data.GetColorPickerRandomIndex().ToString();
        var rand = new Unity.Mathematics.Random((uint)hashString.GetHashCode());

        var randomColorIndex = rand.NextInt(0, _myColorsList.Count);

        Debug.Log(randomColorIndex);
            
        return randomColorIndex;
    }
}
```

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public long ColorPickerRandomIndex = 0;
    private int _increaseVal = 50;
    
    public long GetColorPickerRandomIndex()
    {
        ColorPickerRandomIndex += _increaseVal;
        return ColorPickerRandomIndex - _increaseVal;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class LevelMaker : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Data Data;
        
   private void Awake()
   {
       JsonManager.TryGetLevelCreateDataFromJson(ref Data);
   }
}
```

```cs
public static class JsonManager
{
    public static void TryGetLevelCreateDataFromJson(ref Data data)
    {
        var path = Paths.LevelCreationDataPath;

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            var json = File.ReadAllText(path);
            data = JsonUtility.FromJson<Data>(json);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Data not exists. Creating new one");
            var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data);
            File.WriteAllText(path, json);
        }
    }
}
```

I am updating ColorPickerRandomIndex because I want a little more randomness.

[image: Outputs without shutdown]

[image: What I mean by the shutdown is closing unity on runtime. Like this]

[image: Outputs after shutdown]

Comment: If you serialize `Data` then `ColorPickerRandomIndex` might start with the value of the last session instead of 0.

Comment: Is your `data` object shared among different threads? If that's the case, the access to `GetColorPickerRandomIndex` can be in different orders for each run. Or like Oliver said, the `data` object might be saved between the runs, ie the next run doesn't start at `0` but at any other value ...

Comment: Thanks both of you for answer. Like @OlivierJacot-Descombes said I serialized `Data` class for saving last generation value. I need this number for generating that "little randomess". I'm getting this values on `Awake` method. I going to edit question for a minute.

Comment: @derpirscher as you said value doesn't start from `0` and it's shoudn't. Problem is although seed generation number is correct it is not generating correct values. Btw thanks for your help

Comment: Well, if your seed isn't the same, of course the random numbers are different. If you want a specific level to always look the same,  you should use a fixed seed for each level

Comment: Furthermore, generating levels purely random may not be the best option as you may very easily generate unsolvable situations

Comment: I control every generated level with some of generation condition like how many color should be in level and how many different color will be create in bottle etc. and I have solve class checking is solvable.

As you see above seed number are indirect known. For example level generator start from 0 and find correct colors at number 450, on second level generator seed is starts from 500. Thanks for your commnet @derpirscher

Comment: In general why would `Random.Range` be an issue?

Comment: Do you ever save the data again except the first time you created it? Looks like you will always stick to those once serialized values and always start from there so the rest totally depends on how often your method gets called within one session...

Comment: Because Random.Range is only works on main thread. @derHugo

Comment: Yeah, the data is saving after creatin each successful level. The code little bit long. I don't wanted to make sily long question @derHugo